# Generar automaticamente rutas con laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Bien tengo una base de datos que en ella contiene unas tablas, las cuales son:

> -Categoria.
>
> -Subcategorias.

Lo que quiero hacer es que si yo agrego una categoría nueva no tenga que colocar una ruta nueva, si no que ella se genere automáticamente por la base de datos, es decir, si yo coloco una nueva categoría llamada Autos, pues se cree una ruta que llame a **mipagina.com/Categorias/autos**

No se si me hice entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En sí, no se generan automáticamente . se tendría que generar una ruta global para todos sus productos pero en lugar de como comúnmente se accede a través del `id` se acceda de un campo `slug` o `url` en su tabla. debe añadir un campo en su tabla por ejemplo `url`

En su modelo `Categoria` , en su `mutador` al momento de añadir el nombre , asignar el campo `url` llamando a la función [str_slug()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-slug) para generar una `URL` amigable

```
 /**
 * Mutator for name attribute.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = ucwords($value);
    // asignamos el campo url con nombre
    $this->attributes['url'] = str_slug($value);
}
```

En su rutas

```
Route::get('categorias/{categoria}', 
        'CategoriaContoller@categoriaunica')->name('categoriaunica');
```

En su controlador podría tener algo como esto , por ejemplo para recuperar las  `subcategorias` , *(este método puede mejorarse)*

```
public function categoriaunica($categoria)
{
    $categoria = Categoria::where('url','=',$categoria)->first();
    $subcategorias = SubCategoria::where('categoria' ,'=',$categoria->id)->get();
    return view('subcatexcategoria',compact('subcategorias','categoria'));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias <3 asi si me sirve